# How to Print Submenu Links without any Attribute In Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in selenium and trying to print the links text using LIST.

I am trying to get the text from one demo site, but there is no any single attribute present on the locator. So please help me out. Below is the details which i perform.

Site URL: https://www.nopcommerce.com/

Menu: Product > All Submenu under the Product (total 9 links found) but not be able to print the text of that 9 links.

Screenshot 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o5ZD.png)

Screenshot 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFCnX.png)

Code which i have done:

```
 public void OpenStoreDemo() {
    List<WebElement> MainMenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]//a"));
    System.out.println(MainMenu.size());

    for (WebElement list : MainMenu) {

        String getname = list.getText();
        System.out.println(getname);

        if (getname.equals("Store demo")) {

            System.out.println("Pass");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may help you.

```
public void OpenStoreDemo() {
    boolean isFound = false;
    WebElement MainMenuProduct = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/a"));

    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(MainMenuProduct).perform();

    List<WebElement> lstProductSubmenu =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]//ul/li/a"));

    for (WebElement list : lstProductSubmenu) {

        String getname = list.getText();
        System.out.println(getname);

        if (getname.equals("Store demo")) {

            System.out.println("Pass");
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }


    }
    if(!isFound)
       System.out.println("not found");

}
```

Comment: Getting error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to List<WebElement>" in this line. List<WebElement> lstProductSubmenu =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]//ul/li/a"));

Comment: sorry, it is findElements not findElement. updated answer. `List<WebElement> lstProductSubmenu =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]//ul/li/a"));`

Comment: @Murthi This code prints `Not Found` when I ran it on Eclipse.

Comment: Got the solution, remove Else part and break, it will work. Thanks @Murthi

Comment: @Murthi, can u try with the dynamic XPath, because current path may break in case developer add any UL or LI in the code. 
See this //ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]//ul//a

Comment: try this `//*[@class='top-menu']//*[a[.='Product']]/*[@class='sublist']//*/a`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// to make 'Store demo' button visible, hover to 'product' button
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'top-menu']/li[1]/a")));
actions.perform();

// wait until 'Store demo' button will be clickable
new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'top-menu']/li[1]/ul/li[4]/a")));
// locate element
WebElement storeDemoBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'top-menu']/li[1]/ul/li[4]/a"));
System.out.println(storeDemoBtn.getText()); // will print 'Store demo'
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this kind of xpath : //*[@id='aspnetForm']/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a

Comment: @cruisepandey added a shorter version

Comment: I am getting an issue in printing submenu links, wait is not the solution. When i print the text which is under Product menu then every time it prints white space instead of the text. I need to just print the text which is under PRODUCT menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JS** method for get text from hidden webelement and **dataprovider** for check if menu item is enabled, it  could be like this:

```
 @DataProvider
public Object[][] getProductMenu() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {"What is nopCommerce"},
            {"Why nopCommerce"},
            {"Features"},
            {"Store demo"},
            {"Showcase"},
            {"Case studies"},
            {"Roadmap"},
            {"Copyright notice removal"},
            {"License"}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "getProductMenu")
public void checkProductMenu(String menuItemName) {
    driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/");
    // check if menu item is enabled
    Assert.assertTrue(isMenuItemExistInMenu(menuItemName));
}

public boolean isMenuItemExistInMenu(String menuItemName) {
    List<WebElement> menuItemsElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]//ul/li/a"));
    for (WebElement menuItemsElement : menuItemsElements) {
        if (getHiddenTextByWebElement(menuItemsElement).equals(menuItemName)) {
            System.out.println("Menu item [" + menuItemName + "]" + " is enabled in Product submenu");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//this is JS method for get hidden text from WebElement
private String getHiddenTextByWebElement(WebElement element) {
    try {
        return (String) driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", element);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("Can't return hidden text, occur error: \n" + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```